# PostMessage not working with posting custom message

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, window

I used

`PostMessage(NULL,WM_DUCKWND,0,0);`

where

`#define WM_DUCKWND (WM_USER +4)`

to send user-defined msg to all windows in current thread.

**DETAILS**

this is straight in the main function
(DUCKPROC_CLASS_MSG_NAME and DUCKPROC_WINDOW_MSG_NAME are all user-defined macros)

```cpp
    //create message-only window

    WNDCLASS wndc={};
    wndc.lpfnWndProc = MsgWindowProc;
    wndc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndc.lpszClassName = DUCKPROC_CLASS_MSG_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wndc);

    auto hw=CreateWindowEx(NULL, DUCKPROC_CLASS_MSG_NAME, DUCKPROC_WINDOW_MSG_NAME, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInstance, NULL);


    //post

    PostMessage(NULL,WM_DUCKWND,0,0);


    //message loop

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

and used WindProc like this

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgWindowProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DUCKWND:

[BREAKPOINT][BREAKPOINT][BREAKPOINT][BREAKPOINT]

        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

However, the breakpoint isn't triggered as supposed.

**How's that wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"all windows in current thread."

No, that's not correct. `HWND==NULL` sends the message to the *thread* message queue. That's the message queue you process with your `GetMessage(HWND==NULL)` loop.

`DispatchMessage` is the function which looks at `HWND` in `msg`, and chooses the correct window proc. It does so by looking up the window class of that HWND.

Since `HWND==NULL` does not have a window class, it does not have a window proc either, and the message is not dispatched to any window.

If you want to send `WM_DUCKWND(HWND==NULL)` to all your windows, you'll have to dispatch it yourself. In this simple example, that's as simple as setting `msg.hWnd=hw` for `msg.message==WM_DUCKWND && msg.hWnd==NULL`.

Side note: it really should be `WM_APP+4`; the `WM_USER` range is for messages internal to a window class. The thread message queue is shared by windows, so you shouldn't post `WM_USER` messages to it.